# Optimizing instant notifications

Tags: php, sql, optimization, server, server-side

### Scenario

To deliver instant notifications to the client, I'm sending an AJAX request to a PHP page that checks if there are new notifications: if there are, it outputs them, otherwise it sleeps for 10 seconds before trying again, so it has a basic structure similar to the following one.

```
<?php
$max_attempts = 10000;
for($i=0;$i<=$max_attempts;$i++){
    check_new_notifications(); //checking notifications in an sql database
    if(new_notification){
      echo $notification;
      break;
    }
    else{
      sleep(10);
    }
}
?>
```

### What is missing

While this is great for the client, as it doesn't have to send a request every 10 seconds, but just one, I can't find a better way for the server than to check every 10 seconds if there are new notifications.

### My question

What solution could I adopt in order to avoid the server to constantly check for new notifications?

Comment: Turn the problem on its head--use something like SignalR to push notifications down to waiting clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can:

#### Use polling

However, think about sending a request every 10 seconds.
By using your suggested approach, you are keeping a long connection to the server, which is in turn keeping a busy process/thread.
If this is used only by you, it's fine. 
If it's meant to be used by many users, it's a **huge** waste of resources, since the server will be busy doing nothing 99% of the time.

#### Use Websockets

*This is the thing you need.*
Websockets provide a direct and continous TCP communication between the browser and your server. Check out [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/), that's a great PHP library for websockets on the server side.

#### Use an external service

There are services like [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) which also utilize websockets.
However, you don't need a socket server yourself, but send them an event from your backend. Then their service pushes new data to your browser.